# Filtered portfolio gallery - easing animations with jquery

Tags: javascript, gallery, portfolio

I'm currently working on a filtered gallery. I'm using bootstraps portfolio gallery as a framework. I have the filtering working, but I'd like for that easing animation to happen when I click on a filter tab. Is there a way to do this with jquery?

Here's my code so far:

```
$(function() {
    var selectedClass = "";
    $(".filter").click(function(){ 
    selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
    $(".work").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
    $(".portfolio-item").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale');
        $(".work").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, 300); 
    );
});
```

Is it possible to add `.animate({transform scale(1)});` to the `addClass('scale')` and change the scale to 0 for `.scale` in the css? I'm not too sure how to use `.animate` with the transform tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `css` `transition`

```
.scale {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.portfolio-item:not(.scale) {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: scale(0);
}
```